# How to Design Rspec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I've gone through tutorials and I've learned the basics of RSpec. 
I'm trying to now make a web app, the basic first feature is a search box on the main page
that has a dropdown box and postal code entry. The options are difference Car Brands (Toyota, Ford, etc.) and I intend them to all have the same route (/search), which would show a table of locations, cars sold per year and distance. My mind is completely blanking in regards to what tests to write (design wise, not code). I want to develop good habit, but I'd appreciate ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your search is backed by a controller. I would start to test the individual methods in that controller, e.g. POSTing a search to the search method. Here are some things to test:

- does the search controller and the method that searches exist? e.g. no 404 or 500 thrown by app
- how should it behave if an empty query is being done to the controller?
- how should it react if nothing is found? 404? empty list? => test it
- then move on to actual searching:

  - populate your database with things that can be found
  - search for it and see if the return of the method includes what you were looking for

So, these are the things I would start to tests for...

Comment: is creating tests determining whether a controller exists standard?

Comment: Hmmm, I would not test that, because you will get an error if you access a function in a controller that doesn't exist. So there you have an implicit test for that.